# Check if a polygon has an axis of symmetry in $O(n)$ time

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry, computational-geometry

**Question:** Is it possible to check if an $n$-gon has an axis of symmetry in $O(n)$ time?

**Note:** An $O(n^2)$ algorithm is easy to see: it is easy to check if any given line is an axis of symmetry of the $n$-gon in $O(n)$ time and for any $n$-gon, there are only $2n$ lines that are candidates for being an axis of symmetry — the angular bisectors of the n angles and the perpendicular bisectors of the $n$ sides.

**Further question:** If an $n$-gon has more than one axis of symmetry, is there an $O(n)$ algorithm to find them all?

Comment: Only lines that contain the polygon's center of gravity qualify as a symmetry axis

Comment: There is an old paper that likely answers your question, but I cannot access it: "Symmetry Finding Algorithms," Peter Eades, 1988, [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-444-70467-2.50009-6).

Comment: Thanks for the pointer and the observation.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed that paper I cited in the [comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/387005/check-if-a-polygon-has-an-axis-of-symmetry#comment986908_387005) describes how to determine all
symmetries of a polygon $P$ in $O(n)$ time.
The polygon is first translated so that its centroid is at the origin.
Then a "representation" $L(P)$ of $P$ is constructed.
$L$ is an $n$-tuple of pairs $(d_i,\alpha_i)$, where $d_i$ is the length
of polygon edge $i$, and $\alpha_i = \theta_{i+1} - \theta_i$, where $\theta_i$ is
the angle the edge makes with the positive $x$-axis. So $\alpha_i$ is
essentially the angle between adjacent edges.

A rotation by $2 \pi/k$ about the origin induces a rotation of $L$.
All matching rotations are found using the
[Knuth–Morris–Pratt linear-time string-matching algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%E2%80%93Morris%E2%80%93Pratt_algorithm).
Reflective symmetries are found by equating reflections with reversal followed by rotation. Then again string-matching may be employed.

This algorithm finds all symmetries in $O(n)$ time.
I believe the algorithm as described is due to Glenn Manacher.

---

> Peter Eades,
> "Symmetry Finding Algorithms."
> *Machine Intelligence and Pattern Recognition*,
> North-Holland,
> Volume 6,
> 1988,
> Pages 41-51.
> [DOI](https://doi.org/10.1016/B978-0-444-70467-2.50009-6)

Comment: Just a note. The algorithm was originally published in the Visual Computer (1985) by Jan D. Walter, Tony C. Woo, Richard A. Voltz. The paper called "Optimal algorithms for symmetry detection in two and three dimensions". Also your plot of the algorithm lacks rotational symmetries evaluation (number k is taken from it) required for the symmetry axes finding.

Comment: That paper is available at https://deepblue.lib.umich.edu/bitstream/handle/2027.42/8338/bam3304.0001.001.pdf?sequence=5. I found it rather hard to implement in Python but eventually got code loosely based on it to work.